# Excel VBA: Create two-dimensional array from multiple named ranges(no duplicates), sum columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, array, named-ranges

new here. looking for a VBA solution to merge multiple named ranges and remove duplicates with sum on some columns.
I have 4 variable ranges: "ACTUAL","BUDGET","FORECAST","PYEAR"
I would like to combine these into a single array for consolidation. The ranges of Forecast/Actual could potentially reach 60K rows.
The data range for Actuals looks like:

Vendor# Crop Gen.Group Genetic Week.Comm Date     Actual Budget Forecast PYear

12345   STRA CSTA      AMESTI  22/08/16  22/08/16  3,500

12345   STRA CSTA      AMESTI  22/08/16  23/08/16  3,500

12345   STRA CSTA      XXXXXX  22/08/16  22/08/16  3,500

I want to merge the data based on the headings listed as a Key, summing the values listed in the last 4 columns: Actual, Budget, Forecast, PYear

How do I merge the separate named ranges which are on separate worksheets and create an Array to 1. cycle through and remove duplicates, 2. sum the columns required.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Apologies - I have no clue how to add the code in properly...

Have so far created a Class and Module,but it only deals with one range. I still don't know how to merge the ranges into one before passing through the below code:

```
Option Explicit
Private pID As String
Private pVendor As String
Private pCrop As String
Private pGenGrp As String
Private pGenetic As String
Private pWcomm As Date
Private pDate As Date
Private pAct As Double
Private pBud As Double
Private pPyr As Double
Private pFct As Double

Public Property Get MergeKey() As String
MergeKey = pID
End Property 
Public Property Let MergeKey(value As String)
pID = value
End Property
Public Property Get Vendor() As String
Vendor = pVendor
End Property
Public Property Let Vendor(value As String)
pVendor = value
End Property
Public Property Get Genetic() As String
Genetic = pGenetic
End Property
Public Property Let Genetic(value As String)
pGenetic = value
End Property
Public Property Get GrDate() As Date
GrDate = pDate
End Property
Public Property Let GrDate(value As Date)
pDate = value
End Property
Public Property Get WeekComm() As Date
WeekComm = pWcomm
End Property
Public Property Let WeekComm(value As Date)
pWcomm = value
End Property
Public Property Get Crop() As String
Crop = pCrop
End Property
Public Property Let Crop(value As String)
pCrop = value
End Property
Public Property Get Actual() As Double
Actual = pAct
End Property
Public Property Let Actual(value As Double)
pAct = value
End Property
Public Property Get Budget() As Double
Budget = pBud
End Property
Public Property Let Budget(value As Double)
pBud = value
End Property
Public Property Get Forecast() As Double
Forecast = pFct
End Property
Public Property Let Forecast(value As Double)
pFct = value
End Property
Public Property Get GeneticGroup() As String
GeneticGroup = pGenGrp
End Property
Public Property Let GeneticGroup(value As String)
pGenGrp = value
End Property
```

below is the Module code:

```
Sub DailyVolumes()
Dim eSrc As Range  
Dim wseSrc As Worksheet

Dim vSrc As Variant
Dim cV As cItems, colDaily As Collection
Dim vVarRanges As Variant
Dim vRes() As Variant, rRes As Range

Dim vResults() As Variant
Dim sKey As String
Dim i As Long, J As Long, K As Long

Set wseSrc = Worksheets("CONSOL")
Set eSrc = wseSrc.Range("G1:P1")
Set rRes = wseSrc.Range("G1")
'Read Named ranges to array
vVarRanges = Range("ACTUALS")
vSrc = vVarRanges

'Collect the Daily volumes into a Collection keyed to Merge ID
 Set colDaily = New Collection
 On Error Resume Next
 For i = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
  Set cV = New cItems
  With cV
        .MergeKey = vSrc(i, 1)
        .Vendor = vSrc(i, 2)
        .Genetic = vSrc(i, 3)
        .GrDate = vSrc(i, 4)
        .WeekComm = vSrc(i, 5)
        .GeneticGroup = vSrc(i, 6)
        .Crop = vSrc(i, 7)
        .Actual = vSrc(i, 8)
        .Forecast = vSrc(i, 9)
        .Budget = vSrc(i, 10)
        sKey = CStr(.MergeKey)
        colDaily.Add cV, sKey
'If the record for this Merge ID already exists, then add the values to the existing record
  If Err.Number = 457 Then
        With colDaily(sKey)
              .Actual = .Actual + cV.Actual
              .Forecast = .Forecast + cV.Forecast
              .Budget = .Budget + cV.Budget
        End With
  ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox (Err.Number)
  End If
  Err.Clear
  End With
Next i
On Error GoTo 0


'To minimise chance of out of memory errors with large data
'Erase vSrc
'vSrc = eSrc.Rows(1)

'Write the collection to a "Results" array, then write it to the worksheet and format
ReDim vRes(0 To colDaily.Count + 1, 1 To 10)
  For i = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2)
        vRes(0, i) = vSrc(1, i)
  Next i
  For i = 1 To colDaily.Count
        With colDaily(i)
        vRes(i, 1) = .MergeKey
        vRes(i, 2) = .Vendor
        vRes(i, 3) = .Genetic
        vRes(i, 4) = .GrDate
        vRes(i, 5) = .WeekComm
        vRes(i, 6) = .GeneticGroup
        vRes(i, 7) = .Crop
        vRes(i, 8) = .Actual
        vRes(i, 9) = .Forecast
        vRes(i, 10) = .Budget
        End With
  Next i

  With rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes), UBound(vRes, 2))
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .value = vRes
  End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: "looking for a VBA solution" - you are at the wrong place for that:(. This isn't a free code writing service; please share what you've tried and ask specific questions instead of asking for entire code.

Comment: happy to share what I have, so far created  Class and Module to extract data but only from one sheet. I don't know how to Merge the Named ranges to feed into my code as one Range/array...

Comment: "happy to share what I have" - I meant include relevant parts of the code in your question, the pure information you've already created something won't really help us to understand better your question:(

Comment: Sorry Mate, I'm not sure how else to explain....my question is how can I add the Named Ranges from Multiple sheets into one range/Array. Currently my code only works on one range ie. Actuals. I would like to be able to merge all the ranges/worksheets together before passing through the attached code...

Comment: Why do you need to merge the ranges before passing through the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not really need to merge the named ranges into a single range before processing, just process them one at a time.  Here is one approach:

---

```
Dim arrRanges As Variant, rngCntr As Long
arrRanges = Array("ACTUAL","BUDGET","FORECAST","PYEAR")

'Collect the Daily volumes into a Collection keyed to Merge ID
 Set colDaily = New Collection

 For rngCntr = 0 To UBound(arrRanges)
 vSrc = arrRanges(rngCntr)

 On Error Resume Next
 For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
  Set cV = New cItems
  ...
  ...
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

Next rngCntr
```

---

You could also use a `For Each ...` loop instead, but with such a small array, I doubt you would see any difference.